# My python code isn't returning a value. Please look into the code

Tags: python

So I wrote to code to find if a specific word can be constructed from the list or not. If yes, the it return true otherwise False. But for a specific value it's not returning anything on terminal. Below is the code.

```
import sys
  
  
sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)
  


#CanConstruct
def canConstruct(s, ls,memo={}):

    if(s in memo.keys()):
        return memo[s]
    if(s==''):
        return True
    for i in ls:
        if(s[0]==i[0]):


            if(canConstruct(s.replace(i,''),ls)):
                memo[s] = True
                return True

    memo[s] = False
    return False


print(canConstruct('eeeeeeeeeef',['e','ee','eee','eeee','eeeee']))
```

Only for this input only it's not returning anything. I already used memoization to optimize. Can anyone look?

Comment: Here: `if(canConstruct(s.replace(i,''),ls))`. If `s.replace(i,'')` is the same as `s`, then you have infinite recursion.

Comment: I see you have set the recursion limit to a large number. Is that because you were previously getting a recursion error? Perhaps now the stack is so large that it’s taking longer than you are prepared to wait to hit the new recursion limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
if(canConstruct(s.replace(i,''),ls))
```

If `s.replace(i,'')` is the same as `s`, then you have infinite recursion.

You can avoid that by changing it to:

```
if i in s and canConstruct(s.replace(i,''),ls):
```

After that change, I get:

```
>>> canConstruct('eeeeeeeeeef',['e','ee','eee','eeee','eeeee'])
False
```

And you don't have to raise the recursion limit. That was just making it harder to identify your bug.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach with simple string find method.

```
def canconstruct(targetstr, str_list, memo = {}):
    if targetstr in memo: return memo[targetstr]
    if targetstr == "": return True

    for word in str_list:
        if targetstr.find(word) == 0:
            substr_val = targetstr[len(word):]
            if canconstruct(substr_val, str_list, memo) == True:
                memo[targetstr] = True
                return True
    memo[targetstr] = False
    return False

print(canconstruct("starlord", ["st", "arlo", "star", "lord"]))
print(canconstruct('eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeef', ['e','ee','eee','eeee','eeeee']))
```